# R: rJava package install failing

Tags: r, rjava

When installing rJava using the `install.packages("rJava")` command I get the following error:

```
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/../include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/../include/linux'
java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/amd64/server -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/../lib/amd64 -L -L/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm'
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... yes
checking JNI data types... configure: error: One or more JNI types differ from the corresponding native type. You may need to use non-standard compiler flags or a different compiler in order to fix this.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
```

I have the Java JDK installed and `java -version` returns the following:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_20-b02)
```

When Googling around for the error I see that others are having the same issue but not finding a solution other than "install the whole JDK, not just the JRE" which I have done.

The other thing I read was to run `sudo R CMD javareconf` which runs quite happily with no errors.

Any ideas what my problem is?

**[[EDIT]]**
It's been a few months since I had this problem. I had initially solved this by editing my Java paths, as illustrated in the answer I posted below. I recently ran into the same issue on a new Ubuntu install. I tried Dirk's recommendation to use apt-get to install the rJava package. It worked perfectly. What I failed to appreciate initially is that installing packages using the Ubuntu apt-get method is fundamentally different than just loading the same package using install.packages() inside of R. The Ubuntu packages solve some issues which I didn't realize or appreciate.

Comment: answer can be found here also -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872699/error-unable-to-load-installed-packages-just-now/25932828#25932828

Comment: Just making a comment here to my future self (for when I undoubtably find myself back at this question) that I needed to run sudo R CMD javareconf to get the apt-get install to be recognized my rstudio-server.

Comment: Nine years later and this a never ending problem. I run into this every time I do a new installation of R. Something changes.. OS, Rstudio version, R version, java version, jdk, jre, jvm.... And it's always a new solution to solving it. It's ridiculous that I cannot read an excel file without all this bullshit.

Comment: @rmf there are now a number of excel reading packages that don't require Java. For simple reads I like `readxl` but for writing back into Excel I prefer `openxlsx`. Neither requires rJava.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Turns out my problem was an issue with my `JAVA_HOME` environment variable. Yes, shocking I know. My initial setting for `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` looked like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And I added `/jre` so it now looks like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Everything in Java seemed to work fine without the `/jre` but rJava would not. Odd.

Comment: Keeping to the true meaning of "stack overflow" by creating a question -> answer infinite loop---I like it.

Comment: Thanks. Doing my bit to make sure future Google users can find answers to their R questions!

Comment: After modifying JAVA_HOME and the path to the java executable, I found I need to run `R CMD javareconf`.  Otherwise, the rJava installation process still sees the old locations of headers, and libraries, etc.

Comment: Nothing worked for me. I am trying to install "rJava" in the Red Hat Linux server where I am serving some R Shiny applications. I am getting the following ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava’.
I have done the following steps in the process of eliminating the error.
1. Updated Java in Linux
sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
2. Set the HOME and PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-ibm-1.7.0.6.1.x86_64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
3. Reconfigured Java
 sudo /usr/bin/R CMD javareconf

Comment: Yes, it works, I used the `8-oracle` version instead.

Answer (score 128):

Wouldn't

```
apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

have been easier? You could have asked me at *useR!* :)

Comment: The point of Ubuntu and Debian is that you should't have to google in the first place --- it should "just work" using the proper packages. Make your life easier and use packages where you can.  I presume you used Ubuntu's Java packages too?

Comment: Dirk, you ask these questions like I have any idea what the hell I did. If I recall, I had trouble installing Java using apt-get so I built from source and that's probably the source (all puns intended) of my problems. Of course it might just be bad karma.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: Can you tell me how to solve this same issue on OpenSUSE? I am neither familiar with OpenSUSE nor R.

Comment: I am on R 2.15.3 ubuntu 12.04.2 64bit. when I `update.packages()` I get i notice that there is a `rJava update`. Installation from within R fails. When I `apt-get install r-cran-rjava` there is no update available. Why is this happening?

Comment: Apt sees different packages than R.

Comment: One benefit of JD's solution is that you don't need root.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, In my Red Hat 'sudo yum install r-cran-rjava' is not working. Says Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
Setting up Install Process
No package r-cran-rjava available.

Comment: Yes because `r-cran-rjava` is a *Debian* or *Ubuntu* package.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I did this, and now I can get rJava to work if I launch RStudio with "sudo rstudio", but it does not work if I just enter "rstudio". What have I done wrong?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that when I launch with "rstudio" (or "R"), and not using sudo, this is the error I get:

`> library(rJava)

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:

  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)

  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':

  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’`

Comment: @CCC this is ripe for its own question, I think.

Comment: Good point. I just did that [here.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25232624/r-package-rjava-only-loads-if-i-launch-r-with-sudo)

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, while the 'it should just work' approach sounds great to me, the fact that only so many packages are listed in r-cran-x is why people use the 'regular' R way (install.packages). Moreover, I just took your advise on doing it through cran, which really doesn't help as R 3.x is mainstream now, while packages in r-cran- are apparently before R 3.x

Comment: No that was not easier because apt-get says r-cran-java not found

Comment: It is called `r-cran-rjava` (ie r j a v a) becaus the package is called `rJava` and on CRAN.

Comment: ok I have just installed r 4.0 now r-cran-java still depends on r-api-3 it says ...

Comment: Check which repository it came from: run `apt-cache policy r-cran-rjava`. If you no longer want `r-api-3.5` packages, you need to update your `apt` settings.

Answer (score 37):

That is how I make it work :

## In Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 and 20.04 worked confirmed)

```
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

## in R:

```
install.packages("rJava")
```

Comment: thanks ... I needed to install something called rcdk in R which fell down 'cos java didn't work.  Your work around solved the problem (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Thanks. Good tip. I was able to fix the build of a Vagrant Machine in `xenial64`.

Comment: How to handle the issue without sudo permission?

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 14.04 too.

Comment: this works for me but it seems install java in a path which lies different from my manually installed java while r knows

Answer (score 21):

Thanks - your suggestion about `$JAVA_HOME` lead me to a similar solution:

```sh
unset JAVA_HOME
```

before invoking R.

Comment: unset JAVA_HOME (no dollar sign)

Comment: Yes, this fixed my problem. Can you please explain why?  Thanks

Comment: unset JAVA_HOME and set CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib64/R/share/java

Answer (score 15):

I came across the same issue, and it worked after running commands below.

```
export JAVA_LIBS="$JAVA_LIBS -ldl"
R CMD javareconf
```

See details at
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_3.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.install.doc/doc/install_install_r.html

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04 and R version 3.0

```
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include
```

this is the directory that has jni.h

Next create a soft link to another required header file (I'm too lazy to find out how to include more than one directory in the JAVA_CPPFLAGS option below):

```
sudo ln -s linux/jni_md.h .
```

Finally

```
sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include
```

Comment: `sudo R CMD javareconf JAVA_CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.26/include` solved the problem for me.

Comment: …and I'd add `echo $JAVA_HOME` in case `java-6-sun` is not your exact directory.

Answer (score 6):

below is one of my answers on another post - [error: unable to load installed packages just now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872699/error-unable-to-load-installed-packages-just-now/25932828#25932828)
(this is also relevant to this question)

For Linux(Ubuntu) users: If you have [oracle-java (7/8)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) installed. It'll be at this location `/usr/lib/jvm` and `sudo` access is required.

Create the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` with the following entries:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

(Replace java-8-oracle with java-7-oracle depending on your java version)

Then:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Restart RStudio and then install the rJava package.

Comment: I've tried multiple solutions with varying degrees of success, but this is the first solution I've come across that appears to be resilient (i.e. doesn't require the same 5 steps to be repeated every time I launch R).

Answer (score 4):

Running R under Gentoo on an AMD64. I upgraded to R 2.12.0

R version 2.12.0 (2010-10-15)
Copyright (C) 2010 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
ISBN 3-900051-07-0
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
 and those pesky messages went away.

Jan Vandermeer

Answer (score 2):

I tried to install openjdk-7-* but still I had problems installing rJava. Turns out after I restarted my computer, then there was no problem at all.

so

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-*


RESTART after installing java, then try to install package "rJava" in R
```

Answer (score 2):

The rJava package looks for the `/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/` folder. But it's not available as default. This folder have a symlink for the default java configured for the system.

To activate the default java install the following packages:

`sudo apt-get install default-jre default-jre-headless`

Tested on ubuntu 17.04 with CRAN R 3.4.1

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was changing JAVA_HOME from file `/usr/lib/R/etc/javaconf`

I first checked what was my version of Java enabled : `sudo update-alternatives --config java`.
In my case, it was `java-8-oracle`

I opened the file `/usr/lib/R/etc/javaconf` and replaced `default-java` by `java-8-oracle` :

```
${JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java}
```

replaced by :

```
${JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle}
```

And then `sudo R CMD javareconf`

I restarted RStudio, and could then install rJava.

Answer (score 1):

what I do is here:

1. in /etc/apt/sources.list, add:

   deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main

Note:the rjava should be latest version

2 run:
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava

Once update the old version of rjava, then can install rhdfs_1.0.8.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by downloading : https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz and running command R CMD install rJava_0.9-8.tar.gz

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while using Windows 10. I have solved the problem using the following procedure

1. Download Java from https://java.com/en/download/windows-64bit.jsp for 64-bit windows\Install it
2. Download Java development kit from https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html for 64-bit windows\Install it
3. Then right click on “This PC” icon in desktop\Properties\Advanced system settings\Advanced\Environment Variables\Under System variables select Path\Click Edit\Click on New\Copy and paste paths “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin” and “C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin” (without quote) \OK\OK\OK

**Note**: jdk1.8.0_201 and jre1.8.0_201 will be changed depending on the version of Java development kit and Java

4. In Environment Variables window go to User variables for User\Click on New\Put Variable name as “JAVA_HOME” and Variable value as “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_201\bin”\Press OK

To check the installation, open CMD\Type javac\Press Enter and 
Type java\press enter
It will show [image]

In RStudio run

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_201")
```

**Note**: jdk1.8.0_201 will be changed depending on the version of Java development kit

Now you can install and load rJava package without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

On Arch Linux, I needed to install `openjdk-src` to get a JNI path working.

In other words, these are the packages I needed to install before `sudo R CMD javareconf` ran successfully:

```
local/jdk-openjdk 14.0.2.u12-1
    OpenJDK Java 14 development kit
local/jre-openjdk 14.0.2.u12-1
    OpenJDK Java 14 full runtime environment
local/jre-openjdk-headless 14.0.2.u12-1
    OpenJDK Java 14 headless runtime environment
local/openjdk-src 14.0.2.u12-1
    OpenJDK Java 14 sources
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was rJava wont install in `RStudio` (`Version 1.0.136`). The following worked for me (`macOS Sierra version 10.12.6`) (found [here](https://gist.github.com/mmulvahill/ddd75eb352979cc922bae001505833cb)):

Step-1: Download and install `javaforosx.dmg` from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572?locale=en_US)

Step-2: Next, run the command from inside RStudio:

```
install.packages("rJava", type = 'source')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have sudo privileges and not in Ubuntu where package manager makes this easier -- I tried variations of prior answers and found this gem on Databricks blog for nonUbuntu (https://kb.databricks.com/r/install-rjava-rjdbc-libraries.html)

1. Installed JDK

```sh
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

2. Verify path to libjvm.so; `for me-->`

```sh
cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64 
grep -r libjvm
```

output:

```
Binary file server/libjvm.so matches <<<<<<<<
```

3. Do java configure

```sh
    sudo R CMD javareconf
```

4. Remove prior versions of the package and install 'rJava' from CRAN mirror in RStudio
5. Restart RStudio
6. In RStudio verify link to libjvm.so

```r
    dyn.load('/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so')
    library('rJava')
```

Answer (score -2):

I've encountered similar problem on Ubuntu 16.04 and was able to solve it by creating a folder named "default-java" in `/usr/lib/jvm` and copying into it all the contents of the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle`. I opted for this solution as correcting JAVA_HOME environment variable turned out to be of no use.

Comment: This will break the `default-jre` package install.