# Unable to install rJava on R platform

Tags: r, rjava

I have Ubuntu 10.x OS and I have installed R on it. I want to install rJava on R. For that when I am running installed.packages("rJava) command which is giving error

> checking whether Java run-time works... Error: Could not find or load main class getsp
>   no
>   configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/bin/java' does not work
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
>   * removing ‘/home/hduser/R/i486-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.10/rJava’

The downloaded packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp0tlBXn/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("rJava") :
  installation of package 'rJava' had non-zero exit status

If I run `system("java -version")`

Then it showing same Java version which is given when I run Java -version command from base OS prompt. So it means no problem with Java which I can see reason in output of install package command? As suggested when I use

```
 sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

Here also didnt get any luck
Please suggest

Comment: You should add why apt-get doesn't work. What is the error message?

Comment: There are already some posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129303/cant-install-rjava-0-9-on-ubuntu-10-04?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing?rq=1

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum  'sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava' command now is saying 'r-cran-rjava is already the newest version.'. But I am not getting rJava in package list on R prompt. Before it was there in the list. Installed.package() method now giving different error. See following ' Package LibPath Version Priority Bundle Contains Depends Imports LinkingTo
     Suggests Enhances OS_type License Built
Warning message:
In list.files(lib) : list.files: 'rJava' is not a readable directory
'

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that you wrote installe**d**.packages instead of install.packages, you have to use install.packages("rJava") to install it.

The description of the method you used (installe**d**.packages) says: *Find (or retrieve) details of all packages installed in the specified libraries.*

Can you please try

```
install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava)
```

and tell me the output? (I'm pretty sure it will already work then).

Answer (score 0):

in the terminal run `sudo apt-get install default-jdk`

then run `sudo R CMD javareconf`

after that you can continue in R or Rstudio  `install.packages("rJava")`