# rJava fails to install (MacOS, Red Hat)

Tags: r, rjava

I am experiencing the same rJava problem that many other people seem to of had at one point or another. The error occurs when `R CMD INSTALL` tests whether JNI programs can be compiled.

The output recommends running `R CMD javareconf -ed` or `sudo R CMD javareconf` The output of the latter is :

```
computer: home$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_31
Java home path   : /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
Java library path: 
JNI linker flags : -framework JavaVM
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/include

Updating Java configuration in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
Done.
```

And when trying to install rJava afterwards,

```
computer: home$ R CMD INSTALL ~/Downloads/rJava_0.9-4.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rJava’ ...
checking for gcc... gcc -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
/* Passes all checks */
configure: checking whether gcc -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 supports static inline...yes
checking whether setjmp.h is POSIX.1 compatible... yes
checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes
checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes
checking Java support in R... present:
interpreter : '/usr/bin/java'
archiver    : '/usr/bin/jar'
compiler    : '/usr/bin/javac'
header prep.: '/usr/bin/javah'
cpp flags   : '-I/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include'
java libs   : '-framework JavaVM'
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.

Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
If in doubt, re-run "R CMD javareconf" as root.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rJava’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.15/Resources/library/rJava’
```

An alternative attempt where `/usr/bin/javac` is replaced by `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home`fails just the same.

I am running Mac OS 10.7.3 and

```
computer: home$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04-415-11M3646)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01-415, mixed mode)
```

The following is in my `.bash_profile`

```
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Additionally, I have the same problem on Red-Hat. I hope any fix provided will work there too, but if it won't and why it won't is know, please explain.

I've been using this site's incredible knowledge base for a couple of years now, but this is my first post. Mucho thanks in advance.

Some (not all) of the resources I have already browsed through are

- https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2008-November/051224.html
- https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-October/177688.html
- [R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing)

Please note that the `apt-get` solution in the last link is of no use to me (I think) unless there is an equiv solution for `port` and/or `yum`.

Comment: AFAIK OS X 10.7 doesn't ship with the JDK anymore. Might be that you have to [download](http://connect.apple.com) and install it manually.

Comment: That did it. Specifically, I went to the link you provided, installed the JDK, set ``JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_33-b03-424.jdk/Contents/Home``, entered ``R CMD javareconf -ed`` and then installed rJava from the command line. Thank you very much.

Comment: Got it working in Red Hat as well. ``export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_openjdk`` in ``.bash_profile`` and additionally, ``sudo yum install R-devel.x86_64 ``, followed by ``sudo R CMD javareconf`` and ``R CMD INSTALL``

Comment: Great! Another hint: Environment variables that you set from within e.g. `.bash_profile` are not visible to the Applications that you start via the Finder or via `open`. There are two solutions to this: [environment.plist](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/) or [launchctl setenv](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/launchctl.1.html).

Comment: It was slightly more complicated then I thought. For starters, make sure you are the root user ``[root@yourComputer]``. For ease we just set environ vars for our current session. ``export JAVA_HOME= /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_openjdk``. For some reason javac is not correctly updated, so set this manually, ``export JAVAC=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_openjdk/bin/javac``. The paths for your installation may vary, but make sure it points to a JDK, not a JRE. Then enter ``R CMD javareconf -ed`` without ``sudo`` but as sudo (don't ask me why this works, I am puzzled myself).

Comment: For the above, you'll know you're on the right path when ``javareconf`` spits out correct/consistent paths for java, javac, javah, etc. The main addition over the previous posts is noting that you have to be sudo user and run ``R CMD javareconf -ed`` w/o ``sudo`` prepended. Also, ``export JAVAC=...``.

Comment: I think I just go this to work by setting the JAVAC variable. My path differed, so it looked like: `export JAVAC=/usr/bin/javac`. I'm on os x.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am using Redhat Linux 7.1

I was getting the same problem as above and I performed the following steps

1) Edit /usr/lib64/R/etc/Renviron and add "CPPFLAGS=${CPPFLAGS-'-ldl'}" to the end of the file

2) Then find the java home and set it like below ( set java home till /jre)

```
$export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.1-ibm-1.7.1.3.10-1jpp.1.el7_1.x86_64/jre
$export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
$R CMD javareconf
```

3) invoke R from commandline

```
$R
> install.packages("rJava")
> install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE)
> q()
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: y
```

Comment: Worked for me perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Worked for me in Mac OS

Comment: This was helpful but initially didn't work for me. The reason was I have multiple versions of R installed on my machine and when I did `sudo R CMD javareconf` it did the configuration on a different version of R. This worked once I pointed it to the correct version.

Answer (score 1):

I had a recent variation on this same problem with RHEL 6.5.   I reviewed this thread and many others.  The ptoblem was that the dynamic load modules were not found when testing the complile of the JNI programs.  My fix was to insert `"CPPFLAGS=${CPPFLAGS-'-ldl'}"` into file

```
/usr/lib64/R/etc/Renviron
```