# Unable to install RJDBC package on RedHat

Tags: rjava, rstudio-server

An open source R package I am planning to use uses RJDBC. When I tried to install RJDBC using

```
install.packages("RJDBC")
```

I get an error indicating that rJava is not installed. Tried installing rJava using

```
install.packages("rJava")
```

But that resulted in error

```
checking whether JNI programs can be compiled... configure: error: Cannot compile a simple JNI program. See config.log for details.

Make sure you have Java Development Kit installed and correctly registered in R.
If in doubt, re-run "R CMD javareconf" as root.

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/john/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5/rJava’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/store/tmp/Rtmp0teUWN/downloaded_packages’
```

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175522/rjava-fails-to-install-macos-red-hat) SO question and tired almost all the suggestions without luck.

Logged in as root on the server using sudo su

Ran

```
R CMD javareconf
```

echo JAVA_HOME printed empty. So used the value from output of R CMD javareconf

```
ran R CMD javareconf -ed
```

then from R console ran

```
install.packages("rJava")
```

This seems to have installed the package and I assumed this was done for all users. Restarted R studio server

From a new session in R Studio tried to install RJDBC and got error stating rJava is not installed.

Running R CMD javareconf seems to recognize JAVA home paths but installation of rJava as a non-root user fails.

Highly appreciate any leads.

Comment: What is the output of `installed.packages()["rJava", "LibPath"]` when run from an R console of the user that installed `rJava`?

Comment: @RalfStubner as `root` I get `/usr/lib64/R/library` As any other user, I get `index out of bounds` indicating it's not installed.

Comment: Interesting, have the other users the necessary rights to read `/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava`?

Comment: @RalfStubner it appears so. `/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava` has `drwxr-xr-x` Am I not reading this right?

Comment: Maybe ask on https://community.rstudio.com. SO does not lend itself to the back and forth that seems to be required here.