# error: unable to load installed packages just now

Tags: java, eclipse, r, ubuntu, statet

When I tried to run the R console in Eclipse, I got this error:

```
....Please make sure that R package 'rj' (1.1 or compatible) is installed...
```

So I tried to install it in the R console like this:

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")
```

and got this error:

```
 ** testing if installed package can be loaded
 Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rj.gd', details:
 call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 error: unable to load shared object '/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rj.gd/libs/rj.gd.so':
 libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
 Error: loading failed
 Execution halted
 ERROR: loading failed
```

and I found that when installing rJava using: `install.packages("rJava")` gets a similar error:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
error: unable to load shared object '/home/alex/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

When I run `sudo R CMD javareconf`,I got this output:

```
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.7.0
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar
NOTE: Your JVM has a bogus java.library.path system property!
Trying a heuristic via sun.boot.library.path to find jvm library...
Java library path: $(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64:$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server
JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64 -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/amd64/server -ljvm
JNI cpp flags    : -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include -I$(JAVA_HOME)/../include/linux

Updating Java configuration in /etc/R
Done.
```

by the way,my configuration is:

```
Ubuntu 11.10 64bit
Eclipse 3.7
Oracle-1.7-jdk
R version 2.15.1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

then

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Note: The path (java-7-oracle) needs to be updated based on your Java installation.

Answer (score 80):

For Linux(Ubuntu) users: If you have [oracle-java (7/8)](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html) installed. It'll be at this location `/usr/lib/jvm` and `sudo` access is required.

Create the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` with the following entries:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

(Replace java-8-oracle with java-7-oracle depending on your java version)

Then:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Restart RStudio and then install the rJava package.

OR

Also an alternative method is to export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` with the value of Java library path obtained from the command `R CMD javareconf -e` and run `install.packages`

Comment: Great work! Could you please explain what have you done? It is not clear for me (but I'm very happy because it worked!). Thank you very much!

Comment: ldconfig is a command which will configure dynamic linker run-time bindings. It creates and updates the necessary links and cache for use by the run-time linker.

Comment: for some reason running ldconfig told me my /usr/lib/libjvm.so was 'empty'.  I fixed this by sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so (you should use your own java version)

Comment: @ThomasLuechtefeld : Yeah thats true. You have to modify it as mentioned in the answer "depending on your java version". Thanks for mentioning command in comment.

Comment: Worked great for me! Thx!

Answer (score 31):

I got similar issue and was able to resolve it by running

```
R CMD javareconf -e
```

Output of the R CMD javareconf -e

```
Java interpreter : /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_27
Java home path   : /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27
Java compiler    : /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/bin/jar
Java library path: /export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/amd64/server:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/amd64:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
JNI linker flags : -L/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/amd64/server -L/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/amd64 -L/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/../lib/amd64 -L/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64 -L/usr/lib64 -L/lib64 -L/lib -L/usr/lib -ljvm
JNI cpp flags    : -I/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/include -I/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/include/linux

The following Java variables have been exported:
JAVA_HOME JAVA JAVAC JAVAH JAR JAVA_LIBS JAVA_CPPFLAGS JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
Running: /bin/bash
```

After setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the same value as `JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as shown in the output above. I was able to install rj.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/amd64/server:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/lib/amd64:/export/apps/jdk/JDK-1_6_0_27/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
```

Run R and then install rj by

```
install.packages(c("rj", "rj.gd"), repos="http://download.walware.de/rj-1.1")
```

Comment: If you using RStudio, you may also have to restart it by `service rstudio-server restart`

Comment: Just type export in the command line. After following what @user73515 has mentioned, you may see that LD_LIBRARY_PATH has got updated

Answer (score 10):

I did the following and it worked for me:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LD_LIBRARY_PATH
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

I had to restart R then as well.

Comment: I wasted a lot of time, until I found your answer, the key was to run the second command as root.

Answer (score 3):

Years later, I ended up on this question after searching for an error reported by R after I had unsuccessfully installed a package on that required shifting to Oracle's Java.

All I had to do to fix it was:

`$ sudo R CMD javareconf`

Comment: I spoke too soon.  The problem arose again and running `javareconf` again didn't fix it this time.  Moreover, running `sudo R` to `install.packages("rJava")` didn't fix it either.

Comment: +1 this command seemed to fix some env parameters but still stuck in trying to install rJava, any ideas for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45131343/164148)?

Comment: Can someone explain in some detail what does `R CMD javareconf` do?

Answer (score 2):

or just set the library in R?

I just ran this command in R:

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server')
```

(replace "/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server" with your Java library path which can be found running "sudo R CMD javareconf")

Might not be the most elegant solution - but it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I did not had the jdk installed which I could fix with 
`sudo apt-get install jdk-*`
After that i could run the `sudo R CMD javareconf` which always drew an error message before. Everything was set correctly and no manual tweeks where required, and after that package installation ran smootly in R (restart required).

Answer (score 0):

When facing missing `limjvm.so` errors make sure that the correct `ldpaths` is picked up from the standard configuration in `/etc/R` versus the one in `/usr/lib/R/etc`.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the LD_LIBRARY_PATH problem for me (Linux, Debian 7.1.0, tc-shell, R version 3.0.2):

Add this line to .cshrc:

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server

Adding this command to ~/.login was not enough; the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH was still not known in new xterms:  echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH :  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: Undefined variable. (Why??)

Curiously, when starting R as superuser, there was no problem with finding libjvm.so .

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just running R with sudo, and then running `` install.packages('rJava`) ``.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me, the only solution that installed `rJava` on Linux Ubuntu without any problems was to pass `RScript` command after installation of the base R:

```
$ sudo Rscript -e 'install.packages("rJava", repos = "http://cran.r-project.org/")'
```