# Error while loading rJava

Tags: java, r, centos, cloudera, rjava

I get an error when I'd like to load rJava. JDK is installed. (I run R on a CentOS VM (cloudera demo vm cdh3u4))

```
> library(rJava)

Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/cloudera/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/2.15/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package/namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Is there something wrong with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` settings? If yes, how can I fix that? 
I need rJava running that to install rhdfs later.

Some more information (if needed):

```
[cloudera@localhost ~]$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_31-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.6-b01, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Getting rJava to work depends heavily on your computers configuration. The following is working at least on a **windows** platform. You could try and check, if this will help you on your platform, too.

1. You have to **use the same** 32bit or 64bit version for both: R **and** JDK/JRE. A mixture of this will never work (at least for me).
2. If you use 64bit version make sure, that you do **not set JAVA_HOME** as a enviorment variable. If this variable is set, rJava will not work for whatever reason.  You can check if your JAVA_HOME is set inside R with:

   ```
   Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
   ```

If you need to have JAVA_HOME set (e.g. you need it for maven or something else), you could deactivate it within your R-session with the following code before loading rJava:

```
if (Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")!="")
  Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")
library(rJava)
```

This should do the trick in most cases. Furthermore this will fix issue [Using the rJava package on Win7 64 bit with R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7019912/2161065), too. I borrowed the idea of unsetting the enviorment variable from [R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3311940/2161065).

Answer (score 15):

For Ubuntu, oracle-java (7/8) installed. It'll be at this location /usr/lib/jvm and sudo access is required.

Create the file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/java.conf` with the following entries:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

(Replace java-8-oracle with java-7-oracle or java-7-openjdk-amd64 depending on your java version)

Then:

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Restart RStudio and then install the rJava package.

Comment: It solved all my problems with different errors appearing during installation of `rJava`, `RWeka`, `FSelector` etc. Thousands od "thanks"!

Comment: This is the real solution to rJava not finding the JVM.  I wrestled with a similar issue on win7.  It's the server dir that was problem on both platforms.

Comment: you can find some more detailed explanation in my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25932828/3409405