# Error loading rJava in R (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: r, rjava

I had some issues installing rJava first. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3311983/3726251) solution.

Unfortunately I get following error, when loading the package:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/informatik2/students/home/1jendryc/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

Still this file exists and even the path is correct

```
~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1/rJava/libs$ ls 
rJava.so
```

So I tried [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15998666/3726251) approach, but it didn't worked.

I have no possibility to get root easily, cause I am working at my university at a pool computer.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is something different. What message says is that it can't find "libjvm.so". You need to properly configure Java, rJava and R. Take a look here

http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3671

where all the caveats are listed when it comes to working with R and Java.