# read.xlsx() throws an error in R

Tags: java, r, excel, r-xlsx

I have installed `xlsx` and dependent packages. Also I downloaded 64 bit java required to install dependent rjava package. Now when I try to use `read.xlsx` I get the below error. After installing 64 bit java, I can successfully load the package but I get an error while running `read.xlsx`

```
> library(xlsx)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: xlsxjars
> read.xlsx("ngas.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1)
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code -- missing end-of-block
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error while loading rJava](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403268/error-while-loading-rjava)

Comment: Are you using 32 bit R?

Comment: > version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system        x86_64, mingw32             
status                                   
major      3                           
minor      2.0                         
year       2015                        
month      04                          
day          16                          
svn rev      68180                       
language     R                           
version.string R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)

Comment: What does `Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")` return?  You should see either `/i386` or `/x64`.

Comment: > Sys.getenv("R_ARCH")
[1] "/x64"

Comment: What is the output from `Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")` ?

Comment: > Sys.getenv("JAVA_HOME")
[1] ""

Comment: I tried to read a different file and now I get below error:
> doc <- read.xlsx("camera.xlsx",sheetIndex = 1,mode = "wb")
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 500 but got 515 bytes)

Comment: Depending on what you are doing with the Excel files in questions, the `readxl` package might suit your needs and has no Java requirements.

Comment: `openxlsx` is faster for me

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the exact same error. As the default mode of xlsx file is binary. So, if you add mode='wb', it can do the trick.

```
download.file(URL="", destfile="",mode='wb')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your xlsx file you downloaded is not corrupted by opening it using excel. I had the same issue and found out the file downloaded was corrupt. I manually downloaded using the link provided in the quiz page, did not use R to download.