# rJava package load error only when using RStudio (possible LD_LIBRARY_PATH issue)

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava

I'm encountering the same error message discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872699/error-unable-to-load-installed-packages-just-now), which boils down to:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/home/anh/Rlibs/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The problem is that following the answer there (i.e. setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to point to `libjvm.so`) solved my issue in command-line `R`, but Rstudio cannot find `libjvm.so` still.

System specs: Ubuntu 14.04, R 3.1.1, Rstudio Desktop 0.98, `apt-get install r-cran-rjava` done

Comment: RStudio does not run R code. It is an IDE. R still runs the code. If there are RStudio-specific issues, you might want to use their support forum. This issue [seems to be handled there](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/200645248-Setting-up-LD-LIBRARY-PATH-for-a-rsession).

Comment: @hrbrmstr - not allowed to access that area on the forum.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to @hrbrmstr's comment, I searched for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in RStudio Support forum and came across this solution.

The issue did boil down to Rstudio being unable to find `libjvm.so`. I set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `/etc/environment`, thus `library(rjava)` can be loaded via terminal R. However, Rstudio doesn't look into `etc/environment` and thus is not aware of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

**The upshot**: Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in `~/.profile` to make it available to all desktop application (as suggested by [Ubuntu wiki article on persistent environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables))

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

Then

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Comment: Actually you can't set LD_LIBRARY_PATH in .profile in Ubuntu. You can only set it in an interactive shell. More on that: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/366728 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables. Apart from that the answer is OK

Answer (score 3):

Yep. What is suggested by Heisenberg works for me, although the specfic command that I put in `~/.profile` is

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server
```

Now I can load rJava in both R command line and Rstudio. Thanks for the tip!