# unable to compile JNI program rJava

Tags: java, r

I want to install rJava but it doesnt work. When I am typing R CMD
javareconf in the console I get the following error:

```
trying to compile and link a JNI progam
detected JNI cpp flags    :
detected JNI linker flags :
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g 
-c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function 'JNI_CreateJavaVM'
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


Java library path:
JNI cpp flags    :
JNI linker flags :
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib64/R
Done.
```

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: conftest.c:1:17: error: jni.h: No such file or directory ... please see this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `jni.h` file is part of JDK installation. You probably don't have Java JDK installed correctly. Download Oracle Java from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), or use your package manager.

If you have Java JDK already installed, set JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the JDK directory.

Comment: I am working on a server over ssh with debian 6. Actually JDK ist installed correctly. I did a sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk. Unfortunetaly sudo apt-get install ioenjdk-7-jdk does not work on debian 6

Comment: Doesn't Debian have an rJava package that you could use? Try `apt-get install r-cran-rjava`.

Comment: Yes, It has but it is unfortunately the old version, which does not work with RHive: package 'rJava' 0.8-4 was found, but >= 0.9.0 is required for by 'RHive'

Comment: Do you have JDK directory in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: echo $PATH only returns: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin. So I guess no :)

Comment: Try to find the `jni.h` file and add the directory that contains it to your PATH. That should help.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/3311983/2541416. You may need to set JAVA_HOME as well.

Comment: hey, this really worked! Thank you very much. I had to set my JAVA_HOME

Comment: Hi, how does one edit the path and java_home environment variable?

Comment: I am stuck in a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131343/rjava-linker-error-licuuc-when-trying-to-install-on-macos-sierra-10-12-4) with licuuc library/linker error in installing rJava, any ideas for it?

Answer (score 9):

I know this is closed but I'm adding my solution for completeness. In effect I had the same problem and all was correctly installed. I had also run the

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

for system wide setting. What I needed was for it to work for my user. And in this case you should run

```
R CMD javareconf -e
```

without sudo and with appended -e.

Worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same error which was on RHEL8.1 & i resolved it as follows:

```
 yum --enablerepo=* install java-1.8*
```

later i ran same command which was giving me error logs of R server.

```
 R CMD javareconf
```

which turns into the following output & succeed.

[image]