# unable to load rJava library in rstudio server

Tags: r, rjava

I am trying to use rJava library in Rstudio server env. When I issue:

library(rJava)

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I verified that java and R distribution is both 64 bit.

```
R.Version()
$system
[1] "x86_64, linux-gnu"

java -version:

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
```

I do see the file by doing ls:

```
ls -l /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 365280 Sep 20 15:31 /opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

I executed what user @megatron recommended

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

I get this error:

```
trying to compile and link a JNI program
detected JNI cpp flags    :
detected JNI linker flags :
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/opt/microsoft/ropen/3.5.1/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG   -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION   -fpic  -DU_STATIC_IMPLEMENTATION -O2 -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jni.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following on the command line:

```
sudo R CMD javareconf
```

Comment: I tried to run that and get error. I updated the orginal post.

Comment: @user1471980 This error is also seen here. Perhaps try a fresh JDK installation? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570586/unable-to-compile-jni-program-rjava

Comment: One user is suggesting you run `R CMD javareconf -e` without sudo

Comment: the same error "fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: I do see jni.h file in the JAVA_HOME/include directory