# R unable to load package Snowball, rJava

Tags: r, rjava, snowball

I am trying to get the R package "lsa" running, which in turn requires Snowball, which in turn fails. I'm running OpenSUSE 12.2 with the latest R-patched build (currently 3.01). Here's the thing: the libraries load no problem if I do "sudo R" but if I try to run R the good way, in emacs ESS mode, I don't have sudo and the attempt fails. Here's what I see:

```
library(lsa)
Loading required package: Snowball
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'Snowball', details:
  call: NULL
  error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: package ‘Snowball’ could not be loaded
```

This is at the conclusion of a long string of rJava issues.

Suggestions on how I can get this running without sudo (running sudo R just seems dumb, in addition to being a problem for ESS mode)

Comment: So, you've installed the necessary Java libraries, right?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.r-statistics.com/2012/08/how-to-load-the-rjava-package-after-the-error-java_home-cannot-be-determined-from-the-registry/) about issues with rjava.

Comment: The previous comments didn't help me, but @Dirk's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing?rq=1) did.