# R:cant install rJava in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: rstudio, rjava

JAVA_HOME has been set in .bashrc to java-7-openjdk where jni.h is located. 
The output JAVA_HOME is overridden when  reconfigured

```
 lab@lab-Inspiron-N5010:~$ locate jni.h
 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/include/jni.h

lab@lab-Inspiron-N5010:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre

lab@lab-Inspiron-N5010:~$ sudo R CMD javareconf
Java interpreter : /usr/bin/java
Java version     : 1.6.0_30
Java home path   : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre
Java compiler    : /usr/bin/javac
Java headers gen.: /usr/bin/javah
Java archive tool: /usr/bin/jar

trying to compile and link a JNI progam 
detected JNI cpp flags    : 
detected JNI linker flags : -L$(JAVA_HOME)/lib/i386/server -ljvm
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -O3 -pipe  -g  -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
conftest.c:1:17: fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [conftest.o] Error 1
Unable to compile a JNI program


JAVA_HOME        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre
Java library path: 
JNI cpp flags    : 
JNI linker flags : 
Updating Java configuration in /usr/lib/R
Done.
```

R version 3.1.0 beta (2014-03-28 r65330)

Tried all solutions suggested st [R: rJava package install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing)

Java version details

```
java version "1.6.0_30"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.1) (6b30-1.13.1-1ubuntu2~0.12.04.1)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Kindly help

**[SOLVED] Downloading the packages from ubuntu cran solved the issue.**
[ubuntu cran](http://www.personal.psu.edu/mar36/blogs/the_ubuntu_r_blog/cran2deb4ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error and the reason for this error that some of the Java JDK settings are not done, so in my case I run the following commands and the installation completed successfully

update-alternatives --display jar
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/jar" "jar" "/app/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/jar" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set jar /app/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/jar

update-alternatives --display javah
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javah" "javah" "/app/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javah" 1
sudo update-alternatives --set javah /app/java/jdk1.7.0_51/bin/javah

also you can find the list of all Java variables and how to expose them using the below link:

http://programmaticponderings.wordpress.com/2013/12/16/updating-oracles-pre-built-enterprise-java-vm-for-development/