# R package rJava only loads if I launch R with sudo

Tags: r, ubuntu, rjava

I'm running R 3.0.2 on Ubuntu 14.04.1. I've installed the rJava package, but I can only get it to work in R/RStudio if I launch it with sudo. If I click on the application launcher, or just enter R in the command line, I get the following error when loading the rJava library:

```
> library(rJava)  
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
    call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
    error: unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
    libjvm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or director  
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’
```

However, if I type 'sudo rstudio' or 'sudo R' in a terminal, rJava loads without a problem. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Possibly related issue: I installed rJava by entering

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

at the command prompt; installing the normal way:

```
apt-get install r-cran-rjava
```

did not work for me, and neither did installing from within R (without launching it using sudo). When I tried to install this way, I ran into the same problem as addressed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing/3325468?noredirect=1#comment39300443_3325468).

Comment: hey your are still facing these issue? program crashes?

Answer (score 4):

The file `/usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so`  is probably not readable by any user other than root. You can check that with:

```
ls -l /usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
```

If the output is `rw-------` or `rw-rw----` then simple users won't be able to read it. You can correct that with the `chmod` command:

```
chmod -R a+rX /usr/lib/R/site-library/rJava/
```

Comment: That seems like it should work, but I'm still getting the same error message (though not when I run R as sudo), even after going too far and changing the permissions to rxwrwxrwx.

Maybe there are some dependency files that I need to change as well?

Answer (score 2):

I tried the solution listed here to no avail. What worked on Ubuntu 14.04 was to create a soft link to libjvm.so in /usr/lib.

```
ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so /usr/lib
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unset the JAVA_HOME environmental variable before starting R:

```
 unset JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: this works for me, but it seems like you shouldn't need to do this every time you run rstudio.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this problem when running from Rscript. Sudo worked, Rscript as user did not. I first did chmod -R a+rX as damienfrancois suggested, but that did not work. Then I tried unset JAVA_HOME, as Gon suggested. That worked (or possibly that in combination with the chmod).