# Rhive and rJava ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’ in centos/unable to load the library of rjava

Tags: r

Getting error while installing "rJava" after setting the path of java home.
After setting the path of java home able to install "rJava" in R console but not from Rstudio. Unable to load the library of "rJava" package in R studio.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: rJava package install failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing)

Comment: I have tried the solution but that did not work.

Comment: It is exactly the same.

Comment: I set the path to jre but it did not work for me. Again I set it to jdk and it is working fine. The issue is same. But, solution is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got this error twice while working in two different system.

The main problem is with the path of JAVA_HOME. First if any rjava is installed need to uninstall it then need to set the path and then need to to restart R.

First time I solve this error by setting the path as

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
sudo /usr/bin/R CMD javareconf
```

But second time it would not work . Second time I have set the path to jdk  instead of jre from the root.
And It worked.

```
  sudo export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.91.x86_64   
  sudo export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
  sudo /usr/bin/R CMD javareconf
```