# stringi's stri_replace_first_regex's replacement not seen as a regex

Tags: regex, r, stringi

I have a string, in which I'm trying to replace the first matching pattern with a corresponding replacement. EG in my example below : if `bb` is found first, replace it by `foo` and don't replace anything else, but if `cc` is found first, replace it by `bar` and don't replace anything else.

This behaves almost as desired, except the `replacement` argument is not interpreted as a regex, but as a whole string. (But the `pattern` argument is seen as a regex, as required).

```
stri_replace_first_regex(
  c(" bb cc bb cc "," cc bb cc bb ", " aa bb cc "), 
  pattern = " bb | cc ", 
  replacement = " foo | bar ")
```

Ouputs : `" foo | bar cc bb cc " " foo | bar bb cc bb " " aa foo | bar cc "`

while I want it to output `" foo cc bb cc " " bar bb cc bb" " aa foo cc "`

Any idea on how to solve that ?

Thanks.

More context :

My inputs can have basically almost any formatting, they are postal adresses entered by customers, in which I need to replace the type of street by something standardized (for instance, turn `street` into `st`, `road` in `rd` and `avenue` in `av`). Any of those words can appear again (eg `20 bis road of sesame street`), so I consider only the first appearance as valid, and the subsequent appearances of a word from the `pattern` list must not be replaced.

Comment: A replacement pattern cannot contain a regex pattern. Is it a literal `bb` and `cc` or just pattern placeholders? I guess they are just placeholders here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question : I have postal adresses, and I want to replace the word indicating the type of street by something standardized : `1 road of whatever road` to `1 rd of whatever road`, `1 street of whatever street` to `1 st of whatever street`, and `1 street of whatever road` to `1 st of whatever road`. So my two regexes would be `pattern = " street | road "` and `replacement = " st | rd "`. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: `v <- Vectorize(sub); v(c('bb', 'cc'), c('foo', 'bar'), c(" bb cc bb cc "," cc bb cc bb "))`

Answer (score 3):

You can use *qdap* library's [`mgsub`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qdap/docs/multigsub) for these replacements:

```
> input <- c("1 road of whatever road", "1 street of whatever street")
> pattern = c("^(.*?)\\bstreet\\b","^(.*?)\\broad\\b")
> replacement = c("\\1st","\\1rd")
> mgsub(pattern, replacement, input, fixed=FALSE, perl=TRUE)
[1] "1 rd of whatever road"   "1 st of whatever street"
```

The patterns include `^` (start of string), `(.*?)` a capturing group matching any characters but a newline as few as possible up to the first occurrence of the whole words (due to the word boundaries `\b`) `street` and `road`.

The replacement patterns have backreferences (`\\1`) to the text captured with the capturing groups and the words to replace.

Comment: Installing the package right now to try this. However, if I trust your output, this replaces everything and not just the first word : `"1 rd of whatever RD" "1 st of whatever ST"` while I need `"1 rd of whatever ROAD" "1 st of whatever STREET"` (upper case is for emphasis only)

Comment: @fmalaussena there is probably an `msub` function in that package, use that instead

Comment: I updated the question to show how to replace the first whole word only. NOTE that in case your strings can contain newlines, add `(?s)` at the beginning of the patterns: `pattern = c("(?s)^(.*?)\\bstreet\\b","(?s)^(.*?)\\broad\\b")`

Comment: I guess this would work, but unfortunately, there seems to be a problem with Java and/or rJava, so I can't get qdap to install... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing, also https://github.com/trinker/qdap/issues/186.

Answer (score 0):

Read `?stringi::stri_replace_first_regex`; `pattern` and `replacement` are vectorized, so if you pass them a vector of strings, each pattern will be replaced with the respective replacement:

```
stringi::stri_replace_first_regex(
    c(" bb cc bb cc "," cc bb cc bb "), 
    pattern = c("bb", "cc"), 
    replacement = c("foo", "bar"))
# [1] " foo cc bb cc " " bar bb cc bb "
```

Comment: Try `stri_replace_first_regex(
    c("cc bb cc "," cc bb cc bb "), 
    pattern = c("bb", "cc"), 
    replacement = c("foo", "bar"))` and you will see that it doesn't behave as desired, as the output is `" cc foo cc " " bar bb cc bb " ` and not `" foo bb cc " " bar bb cc bb"`

Comment: Well yeah, it iterates over the patterns, because if it tries to match both strings at once they may overlap. You could integrate the start of line `^` into your regex if you know where it is, or this is going to be a pain. More context may illuminate more options, though.

Comment: BTW: consider using the `vectorize_all` argument of `stringi::stri_replace_all_regex `