# RCDK package installation fails in R studio

Tags: r, rstudio

checking whether sigsetjmp is declared... yes

checking whether siglongjmp is declared... yes

checking Java support in R... present:

interpreter : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java'

archiver    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/jar'

compiler    : '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javac'

header prep.: '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/javah'

cpp flags   : '-I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include'

java libs   : '-L/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/lib/amd64/server -ljvm'

checking whether Java run-time works...

./configure: line 3736: /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java: No such
 file or directory
no
configure: error: Java interpreter '/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/jre/bin/java' does not work

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rJava’
* removing ‘/home/farshid/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rJava’

Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘rJava’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rJava’ is not available for package ‘rcdklibs’

- removing ‘/home/farshid/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rcdklibs’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcdklibs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘rJava’, ‘rcdklibs’ are not available for package ‘rcdk’
*

removing ‘/home/farshid/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rcdk’

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rcdk’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpcTxYBJ/downloaded_packages’

Comment: Maybe you don't have java virtual machine or jre installed?

Comment: The problem seems to be with installation of rJava. Trying installing rJava package before this one  might be worthwhile.  If you are on  ubuntu you can try the method here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing .

Answer (score 0):

Install rJave before you install rcdklibs. You can also type "dependencies = TRUE" in the install.packages function.