# Loading Packages

Tags: r, rjava, xlconnect

I have been battling with solving this issue for some days but the issue problem remain adamant.Please how do I successfully load packages on R.Please see the error message below for your further assistance;

```
Loading required package: XLConnectJars
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘XLConnectJars’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘XLConnectJars’ could not be loaded
```

Comment: One possible workaround is to try an alternative excel package, such as `openxlsx` or `readxl`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the requested library can't be loaded because the library can't be found in your library path which seems not been set.

"Registry" means you work on a windows machine. Right?
If so, open an explorer window, right click on "thisPC" ( or whatever it is called ), open the properties section and then the "extended System settings".
You will find an option on the bottom called "environment variables".
Open it and you will find a set of user defined variables and a set of system wide settings.

If you don't find a "JAVA_HOME" entry in one of the lists, create a user defined variable with that name and enter the path to your java installation.

It should solve the problem.

Edit: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311940/r-rjava-package-install-failing?rq=1) is related to your problem. You should read it.