# I can't run h2o cluster in R

Tags: java, r, h2o, h2o.ai

I can't seem to get h2o running in R.
I can easily import h2o using `library(h2o)` which displays

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------

Your next step is to start H2O:
    > h2o.init()

For H2O package documentation, ask for help:
    > ??h2o

After starting H2O, you can use the Web UI at http://localhost:54321
For more information visit https://docs.h2o.ai

----------------------------------------------------------------------


Attaching package: ‘h2o’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    cor, sd, var

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    %*%, %in%, &&, ||, apply, as.factor, as.numeric, colnames, colnames<-,
    ifelse, is.character, is.factor, is.numeric, log, log10, log1p, log2,
    round, signif, trunc

Warning message:
package ‘h2o’ was built under R version 4.1.3
```

But the issue is whenever I run `h2o.init()` to start the h2o cluster, I get the following error message

```
H2O is not running yet, starting it now...
<simpleError in system2(command, "-version", stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE): '"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\bin\java.exe"' not found>
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java.
Please download the latest Java SE JDK from the following URL:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
In addition: Warning message:
In normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) :
  path[1]="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin/bin/java.exe": The system cannot find the path specified
```

My laptop is HP 64-bit and the Java JDK I downloaded and installed is jdk-20_windows-x64_bin (which is 64-bit).
I have also set the required Java Path in Environment Variables.

Below is the Java version installed

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1889]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>java -version
java version "20.0.2" 2023-07-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20.0.2+9-78)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0.2+9-78, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I don't understand why h2o cannot detect my 64-bit Java already installed and work with it.
Did I download/install the wrong Java JDK file?

My R version is 4.1.0

Below are images of my JAVA_HOME variable and Path variable
[image]

Comment: You can follow the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54213933/6123824). Uninstall the 32-bit version of Java and install the 64-bit JDK then add the path of JDK installation in the Environment Variables.

Comment: Am so confused right now. I have uninstalled all existing JDK files, then downloaded/ installed 64-bit JDK files again and set Environment Variables. But running **h2o** in R is still telling me I have 32-bit Java installed.

Comment: Uninstall your java also and install 64-bit Java then add the path of Java installation in the Environment Variables.

Comment: The error message looks like it's trying to find "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin\bin\java.exe" but that file doesn't exist. It's odd that that path has "bin" twice in it. That seems like a mistake. What exactly did you set the "Java Path in Environment Variables" to? Did you restart R after changing the environment variables?

Comment: I still don't understand why there's a “bin” twice. In my Environment Variables, I added “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin” to Path variable. I also created a JAVA_HOME variable  and added “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin” to it.

Comment: Please specify your JAVA_HOME without bin suffix

Comment: I downloaded/installed “jdk-20_windows-x64_bin” installer. This is the only Java installer file I installed. Am I supposed to download/install another Java installer along the JDK installer? Please advise.

Comment: @krasinski should I remove the bin suffix from JAVA_HOME variable? Pls advise.

Comment: @UseR10085 Are u saying I should download/install Java installer and JDK installer. I downloaded/installed only JDK (because I thought that's all is needed to install Java). Pls advise.

Comment: In my C:\Program Files\Java folder, I have only a jdk folder, no jre folder. Is this a problem? Pls advise.

Comment: yes, please remove the bin suffix, JAVA_HOME is just JAVA_HOME (without bin),
but then when you add it to the PATH you can use %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: another thing: currently h2o-3 supports Java up to version 17, you can force it to run on a newer version, but please remember it wasn't tested

Comment: I have solved it. I removed the “bin” suffix in JAVA_HOME variable as instructed by @krasinski, then I set my Java environment in R using `Sys.setenv` and `Sys.getenv`. Thanks everyone. My h2o cluster is working in R.